# Splitting an RDD[String] type text to RDD[String] type words (Scala, Apache Spark)

Tags: arrays, string, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm working with Apache Spark and Scala and have a text RDD[String] of the lines in the text. I'd like to split it into words (as in split it at every space) and get out another RDD[String] consisting of the separate words.

I've tried splitting the text at every space but don't know how to convert the Array[String] to RDD[String].

```
val lines = sc.textFile(filename)

val words = lines.map(line => line.split('_'))
```

I've also tried

```
val words = lines.flatMap(line => line.split('_')).collect()
```

but am still getting out an Array[String]

As a different approach I've tried to get the indices of the spaces and then splitting the lines at those indices but hit the block every time when having to work with the separate lines with different amounts and places of the spaces and getting the Array[Int] out of the RDD[Array[Int]].

```
val spaces = lines.map(line => line.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 == ' ').map(_._2))
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You got an Array because you called `collect()`, which collects the data from the RDD into a local Array. Just use `lines.flatMap(line => line.split('_'))`.

Comment: Why are you using RDDs given the new century of Spark's DataFrames/Datasets? I'm sure you'll enjoy working with Spark even more.

Answer (score 2):

Use `flatmap` if your `map` operation returns some collection but you want to flatten the result into an rdd of all the individual elements.

```
val words = lines.flatMap(line => line.split('_'))
```

Will turn lines into an `RDD[String]` where each sting in the rdd is an individual word.  `split` returns an array of all the words, be because it's in a `flatmap` the results are "flattened" out into the individual elements.

You already had this but you added a `collect()` at the end.  `collect()` takes all the data from an RDD and loads it into an Array on the cluster.  In other words it turns an RDD into an array.  If you want things to stay in the RDD all you need to do is not call `collect()`

Answer (score 1):

```
val lines = sc.parallelize(List("there are", "some words"), 2)

val words1 = lines.map(l => l.split(" ")) // => words1: Rdd[Array[String]] => word1.collect => Array(Array(there, are), Array(some, words))

val words2 = lines.flatMap(_.split(" ") // words2: Rdd[String] => words2.collect => Array(there, are, some, words)
```

There are two types of Spark Operations : Transformations and Actions.
Transformations are lazy evaluated, otherwhile Actions will return final result to Driver program or write it out to file system.
so, you should consider when you working with a large dataset.

Answer (score 0):

When we read from `sparkContext.textFile` we already have `RDD[String]`
In your case with

```
val lines = sc.textFile(filename)
```

you already have `RDD[String]` 
And the `map` function

```
val words = lines.map(line => line.split('_'))
```

splits the `String` of `RDD[String]` into `Array` thus turning it to `RDD[Array[String]]` 
You still have an `RDD`
Now in case if you are looking for `RDD[RDD[String]]`, you can do

```
val words = lines.map(line => sparkContext.parallelize(line.split('_')))
```

And `flatMap` output every splitted words into separate lines so

```
val words = lines.flatMap(line => line.split('_'))
```

should be of `RDD[String]` 

 And 

 `collect()` turned `RDD[String]` into an `Array[String]`